# NLog Exception when parsing nlog.config - Target cannot be found: 'EventLog'

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm developing a *C# .NET Core 2.2 Web-Api* on *Visual Studio 2017*.
I implement **NLog** 4.6.1 like described on [github](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2).
When I start my application using IIS **NLog does not write into the Elasticsearch**. A **error occurs at the line** at program.cs

```
var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("NLog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

I find a error message at *NLogError.log*:

```
2019-06-12 09:00:49.1606 Error Penter code herearsing configuration from NLog.config failed. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Exception when parsing NLog.config.  ---> System.ArgumentException: Target cannot be found: 'EventLog'
   at NLog.Config.Factory`2.CreateInstance(String itemName)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ParseTargetsElement(ILoggingConfigurationElement targetsElement)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ParseNLogSection(ILoggingConfigurationElement configSection)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.LoadConfig(ILoggingConfigurationElement nlogConfig, String basePath)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogElement(ILoggingConfigurationElement nlogElement, String filePath, Boolean autoReloadDefault)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I tried to shorten my config file to avoid other problems but still same error. The target "EventLog" is to find there.

NLog.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <nlog autoReload="true" throwExceptions="false"
          internalLogLevel="Error" internalLogFile="NLogError.log"
          xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <targets>
            <target name="EventLog" xsi:type="EventLog"
              layout="${longdate} ${level} ${callsite} -> ${message} 
              ${exception:format=Message,StackTrace}"
              source="MonDBSvc" />
          </targets>
          <rules>
            <logger name="MonDbSvc" minlevel="Error" writeTo="EventLog" 
              log="Application" />
          </rules>
      </nlog>
```

The NLog.config file and the program.cs file are on the same root level at the application folder.

I tried writing ***NL***og.config nad ***nl***og.config for the filename and at this code line above.

**What could cause this parsing problem? What could I try to fix it?**

Thanks for support!

When I change the log level from error to warn I get a more explicit message. I'm quit shure that the xml is valid as a xml.

```
2019-06-12 10:27:51.3735 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
2019-06-12 10:27:51.4347 Error Parsing configuration from NLog.config failed. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Exception when parsing NLog.config.  ---> System.ArgumentException: Target cannot be found: 'EventLog'
   at NLog.Config.Factory`2.CreateInstance(String itemName)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ParseTargetsElement(ILoggingConfigurationElement targetsElement)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ParseNLogSection(ILoggingConfigurationElement configSection)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.LoadConfig(ILoggingConfigurationElement nlogConfig, String basePath)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogElement(ILoggingConfigurationElement nlogElement, String filePath, Boolean autoReloadDefault)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2019-06-12 10:27:51.4347 Warn Failed loading config from NLog.config. Invalid XML?
2019-06-12 10:27:51.4597 Debug Watching path 'C:\Repositories\DataPicker\DataPicker\DataPicker.Api' filter 'NLog.config' for changes.
2019-06-12 10:27:51.4597 Debug --- NLog configuration dump ---
2019-06-12 10:27:51.4680 Debug Targets:
2019-06-12 10:27:51.4680 Debug Rules:
2019-06-12 10:27:51.4680 Debug --- End of NLog configuration dump ---
2019-06-12 10:27:51.4680 Trace FindReachableObject<System.Object>:
2019-06-12 10:27:51.4680 Info Found 0 configuration items
2019-06-12 10:27:51.4889 Debug Targets not configured for logger: DataPicker.Api.Program
2019-06-12 10:27:55.2679 Debug ScanAssembly('NLog.Web.AspNetCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c')
2019-06-12 10:27:55.7717 Debug Hide assemblies for callsite
2019-06-12 10:27:55.7717 Trace Assembly 'NLog.Extensions.Logging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' will be hidden in callsite stacktrace
2019-06-12 10:27:55.7855 Debug ScanAssembly('NLog.Extensions.Logging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c')
2019-06-12 10:27:55.7855 Trace Assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' will be hidden in callsite stacktrace
2019-06-12 10:27:55.7855 Trace Assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' will be hidden in callsite stacktrace
2019-06-12 10:27:55.8068 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ApplicationLifetime
2019-06-12 10:27:55.8068 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv
2019-06-12 10:27:55.8178 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
2019-06-12 10:27:55.8465 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator
2019-06-12 10:27:55.8465 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager
2019-06-12 10:27:55.8622 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.CngGcmAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory
2019-06-12 10:27:55.8622 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.CngCbcAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory
2019-06-12 10:27:55.8622 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory
2019-06-12 10:27:55.8776 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlEncryptor
2019-06-12 10:27:55.8776 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository
2019-06-12 10:27:55.9084 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DefaultKeyResolver
2019-06-12 10:27:55.9084 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider
2019-06-12 10:27:55.9084 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Internal.DataProtectionStartupFilter
2019-06-12 10:27:55.9835 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor
2019-06-12 10:27:56.1465 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonPatchInputFormatter
2019-06-12 10:27:56.1465 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter
2019-06-12 10:27:56.1674 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.RazorProjectPageRouteModelProvider
2019-06-12 10:27:56.2420 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker
2019-06-12 10:27:56.2524 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler
2019-06-12 10:27:56.2524 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector
2019-06-12 10:27:56.2707 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.CookieTempDataProvider
2019-06-12 10:27:56.2707 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker
2019-06-12 10:27:56.2814 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector
2019-06-12 10:27:56.2814 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler
2019-06-12 10:27:56.2984 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware
2019-06-12 10:27:56.3256 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware
2019-06-12 10:27:56.3523 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware
2019-06-12 10:27:56.3523 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware
2019-06-12 10:27:56.3592 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeadersMiddleware
2019-06-12 10:27:56.3592 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
2019-06-12 10:27:56.3783 Debug Targets not configured for logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostedServiceExecutor
```

Comment: It could be an issue with the format of the nlog.config file, have a look here: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/EventLog-target

Comment: Hey Donal, I tried using the example from the link you posted but I'm getting still the same error. When I erase the hole tag target I get the error that it is not found. Means to me that it is looking at the right tag target but some how there are problems with it?! Error: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Target 'EventLog' not found for logging rule: MonDbSvc.

Comment: Try removing the rules section

Comment: Add `internalLogLevel="Trace" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log"` as an attribute to your `<nlog>` tag. Then the file will show you what the error is.

Comment: @Priyank Panchal I add the warn log message above at the initial message.

Comment: @Donal Removing the rules section makes no difference. Same error occurs.

Comment: Please note, this error has nothing to do with the format of the nlog.config file (or the casing of the filename)

Comment: Thanks to @PriyankPanchal I found my issue. That nlog-internal log helped me discover that I needed to add NLog.Web to my project(s).

Answer (score 4):

#### About the  Target cannot be found: 'EventLog' error

The "Target cannot be found" error is thrown when the Target class cannot be instantiated. As you could plug in targets into NLog, NLog don't know which are available forehand. Please also note that not all targets are available in all platforms.

The latter is als the case for the eventlog target - is not available in all platforms:

See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventLog-target

> Platforms Supported: Limited (Only available for Net35, Net40, Net45 and NetStandard 2.0. Note: NetStandard 2.0 must use NLog.WindowsEventLog package)

If you're using .NET Core 1.x, it won't work - Microsoft did not port the API because the eventlog is Windows only.

For .NET Core 2 you need to install the [NLog.WindowsEventLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.WindowsEventLog) package and add this in your nlog.config (on top):

```xml
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.WindowsEventLog"/>
</extensions>
```

Please note: the error you're posting will tell that the target is unavailable. The config seems to be valid and no changes are needed in the logger code.  Also NLog.config or nlog.config is not an issue.

#### Elastic search

Maybe I missed it, but why using the eventlog target for Elastic search? There is a Elastic search target. Package https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch

This package supports .NET Standard 1.3+ and .NET Standard 2+

usage:

```xml
<nlog>
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
      <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"/>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="elastic" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all of you!

I got it working, logs are writing into Elasticsearch now. 
My current configuration looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog autoReload="true" throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Error" internalLogFile="NLogError.log"
      xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Network"
        name="CentralLog"
        newLine ="false"
        maxMessageSize="65000"
        connectionCacheSize="5"
        encoding="utf-8"
        keepConnection="false"
        maxQueueSize="100"
        address="tcp://abc.xyz.org:5544"
        onOverflow="Split">
     <layout type="JsonLayout">
      <attribute name="machinename" layout="${machinename}" />
      <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}" />
      <attribute name="processname" layout="${processname}" />
      <attribute name="processid" layout="${processid}" />
     </layout>
   </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="CentralLog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing that I see a File target and not a Elasticsearch one ;)

Comment: @Julian Excuse me, I adjust the file above.

Comment: OK, anyway, for this config `<add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>` isn't needed. There is nothing in your example which uses NLog.Web.AspNetCore. See https://nlog-project.org/config

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced the log attribute in `<logger>` instead of `<target>`. Please try the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog autoReload="true" throwExceptions="false"
  internalLogLevel="Error" internalLogFile="NLogError.log"
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="EventLog" xsi:type="EventLog"
      layout="${longdate} ${level} ${callsite} -> ${message} 
      ${exception:format=Message,StackTrace}"
      source="MonDBSvc" log="Application" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="MonDbSvc" minlevel="Error" writeTo="EventLog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**UPDATE**

Also, please try to initialize your logger in c# file like below:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MonDbSvc");
```

Comment: @FrankMehlhop, please check my update if that helps you.

Comment: @ Priyank Panchal Also this new initialization of the logger does not work. It is not writing into Elasticsearch and of course not using my nlog.config. But it is important, that I can use my configurations.

Comment: @FrankMehlhop, your nlog.config file is configured to write logs in EventLog, not elasticsearch. I don't know how it is linked to elasticsearch. Sorry, I haven't used elasticsearch with NLog. Is your exception gone?

Comment: @PriyankPanchal, you are right nlog.config file is configured to write logs in EventLog, not elasticsearch.

Comment: This is a valid observation (the log attribute was misplaced) but please note, the "Target cannot be found" exceptions has nothing to do with the XML config / layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details here for logging the message:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2

Use this to provide the access to event log:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.WindowsEventLog

Added the tag in the config file:

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Your solution will print the logs in a file, whereas OP is trying to print the logs in EventLog. The solution you provided is very generic and may not be what OP is looking for.

Comment: That's right Priyank Panchal. And the log level *Info* gives also not more detailed information's.

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Target cannot be found: 'EventLog', for this you need to use: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.WindowsEventLog

Comment: @Jayoti Parkash I implement this package but that does not bring me the solution of my problem.

Comment: add assembly at the top of your NLog.config:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.WindowsEventLog" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>

Comment: @Jayoti Parkash I get a exeption for this <extensions ... />

Comment: @FrankMehlhop can you add this tag in the config file before targets option i.e currently missing 
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

Comment: @FrankMehlhop can you post the expception that you are getting for <extensions> tag.

Comment: @JayotiParkash Error EventLogTarget(Name=EventLog): Error when connecting to EventLog. Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.

Comment: It's a security issue, you need allow/add IIS_Users for the same in IIS to provide the access. "NLog.config file are on the same root level at the application folder". or keep the log file at different location and add permissions to that folder for writing the file.

Comment: Ok @JayotiParkash, I changed the path and now I get the same error than before: Exception when parsing C:\Repositories\...\NLog.config.  ---> System.ArgumentException: Target cannot be found: 'EventLog'

Comment: Ok, have a look here if this is the same that you are achieving: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2547